# Building contact list does not complete

Tags: list-manager

I'm exploring EXM 3.4 on an 8.2 rev. 160729 instance and for a simple test mail I imported an existing CSV file which threw constantly an error about an empty listId.

Then I manually created a new list and created a contact in the ListManager application. Now the list is being built but never completing. The message it displays is 'Currently building list. Contacts will be viewable when complete".

```
Please note that this list is currently being built and is locked.
Please note that contacts in the list are currently being indexed, so not all contacts are available to view at this time. 1 out of 1 contacts are currently indexed.
```

Any ideas where it might be stuck? I don't see anything special in the log files.

Comment: I was able to successfully import a simple csv file into 8.2 instance. Does the list have right identifier for all the records?

Comment: No idea, it's an old file I used for ECM 2.1. I'm not entirely familiar with the contact lists and what's required for it to work. To be honest I don't care much about the import issue, it's more building / indexing the new list, as described. I don't know why it it takes an hour or more to create / index a list with one recipient.

Comment: How's ur environment set up? (number of cm, cds, ed).

Comment: A simple local dev environment environment with a clean Sitecore instance

Comment: I usually get that issue when having multiple servers. Can you try with a new list (contacts you are 100% do not exist)

Comment: Yes, this contact doesn't exist. There is only this one list

Comment: I have now manually rebuilt all indexes, restarted IIS and still it tells me the contact list is locked and being indexed

Comment: This is turning into a Q&A session better suited for Slack :-).  Additionally, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://meta.sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/136/what-makes-a-good-post

Comment: i just want to add that this is actually a real problem. im glad my misery has company.I

Answer (score 4):

I can tell you that List Manager has issues. There is a Hot Fix for List Manager that assists with many of these issues, but the one I'm thinking of is for EXM 3.3.  I would be surprised if Sitecore support didn't have a hotfix for 3 4.

I would log a Sitecore Ticket and ask if there is a fix for EXM 3.4 that is similar to hotfix EXM 3.3 135707.

#### Reasons why the list gets stuck

1. Large lists over 200K recipients take hours to complete. It actually takes only about an hour or two to actually get to the point where the list is indexed (assuming nneu@acr.org usable by EXM) But a bug in Sitecore  (assuming for now) either doesn't update the count appropriately (an index 0 vs 1 issue maybe) or the last step is extremely inefficient.

   2. If during the list creation process, Sitecore restarts, there is no restart logic built into List Manager for picking the creation of a list back up. And the list stays "locked" forever.

      - You can fix this by using raw values in Content Editor to empty the Bulk Operation Field, and then setting the Recipients field equal to the number indexed, which is showing in the list (in List manager).

#### Benefits of the Hotfix

- Provides ability to disable list locking. This can improve the overall experience of List Manager
- Numerous bug fixes to EXM.
- Better memory utilization of List Manager.

#### List Completion Issue is still Open

My ticket to Support for why this process takes so long is still open. Once I know of a resolution or have a reference number, I'll edit this answer.

Comment: Thanks Pete. I checked the actual item and everything looks fine. The count is correct and the BulkOperationsId field is empty. Still the list is in that weird state. I guess I really have to contact support or drop that thing completely...

Comment: For what it's worth, the patch is available for EXM 3.4 - https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/140560